# How to capture form info with PayPal transaction

Tags: paypal

I'm offering a backlink building service and I'd like to just offer a simple form on my site where the user can enter their:

- Website they want me to rank
- And 1-2 keywords they're looking to rank for

And then a simple PayPal button that directs them to where they can pay.

Does anyone have any resources they can point me to to capture that information, maybe even their PayPal email, once they make a purchase?

Are there any plugins or code anyone knows of that I can just swipe and modify with my form fields?

I know this has to be possible I just don't know what to type into Google to get more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two parameters that comes to my mind that you could use `custom` & `no_note`
custom is a parameter that you can use to collect the `Website they want me to rank` information and regarding keywords you can use `no_note`(but this has to be entered by the buyer in PayPal checkout page.Alternaltively, you can use `custom' parameter to append both the information and then make a payment.

*Sample Form Code:*

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="website_rank+keywords">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

- Now, how to get this information after the buyer completes the
  payment?

Use [Instant Payment notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/). and look at the [IPN variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) that you can get back